# Can I run .jar file on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, hosting

a very noob question.
Can I run a .jar file on Tomcat. I am not building a web-app. I simply need to run a .jar with 
say HalloWorld in it. Is this possible/appropriate.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using Tomcat for in this scenario exactly?

Comment: Paraphrasing from a comment by Luben in one of the answers: the goal is to host the JAR file on a remote machine.

Answer (score 8):

You can run a Java archive without Tomcat, simply with a Java Runtime Environment:

```
$ java -jar myhelloworldapp.jar
```

Tomcat is a servlet container, only needed for web applications.

Comment: I need to run a .jar on a remote computer(server). So I need basically a Computer with JVM. But I didn't manage to find a hosting which gives simply that - JVM.

Comment: You can still run a JAR using the JVM on a remote machine. I suppose you just need to find a hosting company, correct?

Comment: @Luben "I need to run a .jar on a remote computer(server). ..".  Where exactly is 'Hello World' supposed to appear?  If the client, see the answer re. Webstart, if the server, note that a) some servers run 'headless', and b) the operators of a non-headless server would be disturbed to see apps. popping up on their screen.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what your use case is, but what you probably need is a virtual private server (VPS) provider. They give you a virtual host which runs OS of your choice and you can install JVM on it. There are many VPS' available. Try Linode or Slicehost.

It would help if you would explain what you are trying to achieve, then we might be able to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is Java's [webstart](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like want you want to do is deploy batch code to your server and then run it.  You could either create a new web-app that contains your jar, or add the jar to an existing web app.  Then you can trigger execution with a servlet.  You could even have a JSP that contains:

```
<%
  String [] args = new String[0];
  MyClass.main(args);
%>
```

Of course you'd want to secure that JSP so that not just anyone can run your job.

We use the quartz scheduler to schedule batch jobs from within tomcat.  This let's us monitor our jobs much more easily than if they were run from the command line.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but you are starting the main method every time a client connects to the servlet, executing the JSP script?!