# Run java from FTP

Tags: java, ftp

How can I run a .jar (Java) file on a server using FTP? I use the `ftp` command to enter the server, provide the IP address, username, password. Is it possible to run the java file?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot invoke non-ftp commands using ftp. Use ssh to access remote shell and invoke your commands.

Answer (score 4):

FTP is File Transfer Protocol. It's supposed to be used for manipulating files only.

If you need to run a Java file, I suggest you use SSH, RSH, Telnet, or some other method of getting an actual shell.

Answer (score 2):

You could use FTP to transfer your jar, and then use a crontab, or any other sort of scheduled task, to actually run it. It is not possible to execute commands using FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean using ssh command to enter the server and if so

I think this might be a starting point :
[Can I run .jar file on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588293/can-i-run-jar-file-on-tomcat)

if not I don't think its possible.